# Django - How to create updating progress bars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, progress-bar

I'm wondering how should I go on and implement an updating progress bar. Basically the server should periodically send a confirmation on what is the current progress to the user.

I know how to do an Ajax call with Django and jQuery, which is similar to figure 1.

[image]

On my webpage, what happens is that a "processing" text box appears in the middle of the data the user wants to view.

However, I want to make it so that I could send periodic update to the user. For example, instead of "processing", I want to print out it's currently processing X, Y, and then finally Z, shown in figure 2.
[image]

If I use my method in figure 1, if I send anything back to the server, it will end the ajax request and jump to "success" in jQuery. Is there a way to constantly send data to the user without ending my ajax call?

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the request that generates the dictionary write its progress to a database, and have a second ajax request polling the server to check the progress and report to the user.

Comment: The question is, then how should the two tasks communicate together? I'm using celery and rabbitMQ, and tasks are distributed to celery workers. Should I implement a model that writes tasks status to the database, and another process reads the task status and sends it to a user?

Comment: I'm not familiar with celery or rabbitMQ, but generally speaking, the worker writes any updates to the database, and another process checks the progress in the database to show the user.

Comment: a faster place to do that would be memcached, rather than constantly hitting a database.